# How to sort a CountTable by key in nim?

Tags: nim-lang

In *nim*, I have a CountTable:

```
var
  sizeFreqs = initCountTable[int]()
```

that I would like to sort numerically by key, while `sizeFreqs.sort()` will do this by counts.

I didn't understand the [documentation](https://nim-lang.org/docs/tables.html) about sorting in nim.

Some general guidance on sorting is highly appreciated, as a second case I'd like to implement is sorting by string length if using a `wordsFreqs = initCountTable[string]()` instead.

Thanks
Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would extract the keys of the table to a `seq` and then order the seq to use it as some kind of index:

```
import algorithm  # This provides "sort"

var index: seq[char]

for k in sizeFrequencies.keys:
  index.add k

index.sort()
```

For the second case, you can pass a procedure to `sort`:

```
proc lenSort(x, y: string): int =
  if x.len == y.len:
    return 0
  elif x.len > y.len:
    return 1
  else:
    return -1
```

And then:

```
let myString = @["AAA", "BBB", "BB", "AA", "A", "BBB", "BB", "BB", "BB"]
var wordFrequencies = initCountTable[string]()

for c in myString:
  wordFrequencies.inc(c)

var index: seq[string]

for k in wordFrequencies.keys:
  index.add k

echo wordFrequencies
# Prints {"BBB": 2, "A": 1, "AA": 1, "AAA": 1, "BB": 4}

wordFrequencies.sort
echo wordFrequencies
# Sorted by word count, prints
# {"BB": 4, "BBB": 2, "A": 1, "AA": 1, "AAA": 1}

index.sort(lenSort)
echo index
# Prints @["A", "AA", "BB", "BBB", "AAA"]
```

Note that the last sorting is stable, that is, items with the same length (in this case "BBB" and "AAA", for example) retain the same order of the CountTable.

With `index` you have your CountTable virtually sorted, using for example:

```
for i in index:
    echo echo i, " -> ", wordFrequencies[i]

# A -> 1
# AA -> 1
# BB -> 4
# BBB -> 2
# AAA -> 1
```